# Path difference Vs Phase difference

Tags: waves

I have been taught that path difference and phase difference are essentially the same thing, except phase difference is measured in an angle unit while path difference is measured in multiples of wavelength. This seems incorrect.

I think they are rather different concepts, with path difference representing the difference in distance a wave needs to travel in order to reach a point. Are they really the same thing like I have been taught?

Comment: The point is that a path difference will lead to the accumulation of a phase difference

Answer (score 1):

Yes, path difference is not *equal* to the phase difference, but they are proportional to each other. The proportionality factor is the wavelength in the medium. Hence: path difference $=\lambda\times$phase difference.